# How to get access to each Node in loop from Observer?

Tags: swift, scenekit

When it's clicking on the button, flagObservation works and so it should removeAllAction for each ringNode in the loop.
The problem is: observe doesn't know what is ringNode index.
The question: How to take access to each ringNode created in loop from Observe?

```
import ARKit 
import SceneKit 
import UIKit

final class arViewController: NibViewController<arContentView>{

 @objc let taylor = Motion()
 var flagObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

 func createAndMove(){

  switch CreateSomeThihgs{
    case .first, .second:
         for index in 0..<Array.count {
          ...
          let ringNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
          ...
          ringNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(...)

          flagObserve = observe(\arViewController.taylor.flag, options:[.new]) { (vc, change) in
            ringNode.removeAllActions()   //Delete action 
          } 

         }

       }

    @IBAction func pushPauseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        taylor.flag = 1
    }    
}


class Motion: NSObject{
    @objc dynamic var flag = Int() 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: ringNode write to Array:

```
 let ringNodes = [SCNNode]()
```

Observer take out from the loop, and run loop in observer:

```
flagObservation = observe(\arViewController.taylor.flag, options: [.new]) { (vc, change) in 

  for index in 0..<ringNodes.count { 

    let ringNode = ringNodes[index] 

    ringNode.removeAllActions() 

  }
}
```

(Thanks to Vasilii Ya. for Tip)